# Displaying Single Document from Firebase

Tags: database, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having problems getting data from my firebase. I have the data but do not know how to display it.

Here is my Database:

[image: Thats my database]

This is my code:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {

  final dynamic userUid, nicked;
  Home({this.userUid, this.nicked});



  @override
 _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}




class _HomeState extends State<Home> {



  final int delayedAmount = 500;
  //final AuthService _auth = AuthService();



  void getNick() {
  //get nickname of this User
  final CollectionReference userNickname  = Firestore.instance.collection('NickNames of Users');
  var documentNick = userNickname.document(widget.userUid);
  documentNick.get()
  .then((DocumentSnapshot ds){
      var nick = ds.data['MyNickName'];
      print(nick);
      var nicked = Home(nicked: nick,);
  });
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent[400],

      body:  SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB( 0 , 50, 0, 0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  child: DelayedAnimation(
                   child:  
                    Text(
                             widget.nicked,//This i where the firebase data nickName code will go

                     textScaleFactor : 1,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Comic',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 30,

                    ),
                    ),
```

So i just dont know how to get the single document from firebase and display it.
So this is how i get userUid...

```
  import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
//import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:fruithero/model/user.dart';
import 'package:fruithero/services/database.dart';
import 'package:fruithero/pages/myHome.dart';

class AuthService {
  final dynamic nickNamesofUser;
  AuthService({this.nickNamesofUser});

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  void homeTransporter(uid){
   dynamic homeTransport = uid;
   Home(userUid: homeTransport,);
  }

  // create user obj based on firebase user
  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // auth change user stream
  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
      //.map((FirebaseUser user) => _userFromFirebaseUser(user));
      .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  // sign in anon
  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  // sign in with email and password
  Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    } 
  }

  // register with email and password
  Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      //storing user uid
      homeTransporter(user.uid);
      //create new document for user with the uid
      await DataBaseServices(uid: user.uid).createDocumentWithUid(nickNamesofUser);
      //await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(nickNamesofUser);
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (error) {
      return null;
    } 
  }

  // sign out
  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

}
```

I hope this helps. Sir..............................................................................................................................................................

Comment: where you want to display?

Comment: @SandeepSharma I want to display it in that text widget that says widget.nicked inside.  There is a comment there

Comment: What does ? `print(nick);`

Comment: it does not do anything

Answer (score 0):

```
   String nick,userID;

 void initState() {
super.initState();
userID = widget.uid;
getNick();
print(userID);
}

 void getNick() {
  var users;
  //get nickname of this User
 Firestore.instance.collection('NickNames of Users').document(userID).get().then((data){
    setState(() {
      users = data;
      nick = users['MyNickName'];
      print(nick); 
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: ok thanks.. Please can you show me you putting it in a stateful widget like my example, and also please put the value in the text widget.. thanks

Comment: You can use as `Text(nick)`

Comment: Its giving an error:    its sayind a string most be provided to text widget and not a null value

Comment: Sir it said the same thing

Comment: I/flutter ( 7263): Another exception was thrown: A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
I/flutter ( 7263): Another exception was thrown: A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.

Comment: check `print(widget.userUid)`

Comment: i cant even find what it print(nick) says. the error is to long

Comment: Just check userUid is not null.

Comment: how do i check it

Comment: just `print(widget.userUid);`

Comment: OK.. Let me check.. Or should i just show my code that gets the userUid?

Comment: OK sir i have update it... I didn't get your question

Comment: please can anyone help please

Comment: Try checking your uid is not null. `print(widget.userUid);` insted of `print(nick);`

Comment: I/chatty  (21645): uid=10203(com.example.food_timetable) 1.ui identical 1 line                   Am not sure is that it

Comment: Apparently it is returning null                                                                                                                                           E/flutter ( 7734): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.     
E/flutter ( 7734): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 7734): Tried calling: []("MyNickName")
E/flutter ( 7734): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter ( 7734): #1      DocumentSnapshot.[] (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:29:42)

Comment: I think the problem is with the home transporter in my code.. Any help for that